# Помогите разобраться с союзами

Tags: морфология

Не пойму являются ли союзами  **"который",  "где" и  "какой"**(какою). Может это союзные слова? Ведь союзные слова к союзам не относятся .... у них какая-то синтаксическая функция есть...хотя я не понимаю как их отличать.

> 1.Больше всего она при свидании с ним боялась за смущение, **которое**, она
>   чувствовала, должно было овладеть ею и выдать ее, как скоро она его
>   увидит.
>
> 2.Лес, в **который** я вошел, был част и глух, так что я с трудом добрался до места, **где** упала птица...

В Викисловаре пишут *"где"* - союзное слово (Я устал ото всего и пошел туда, где я мог наконец отдохнуть).

> 3.Мастер ли ты был, или просто мужик, и **какою** смертью тебя прибрало?

Наверное *какою* - это вопросительное местоимение?

Answer (score 3):

"который", "какой" и "где" - не являются союзами. "Какой" и "который" - вопросительно-относительные местоимения, в сложноподчинённом предложении - союзные слова, т.е. выполняют ещё и роль союза, присоединяя придаточное.

"Где"-местоимённое наречие. В СПП тоже союзное слово.

**Подчинительные союзы:**

Когда, едва, пока, с тех пор как;

потому что, оттого что, так как, ибо; благодаря тому что;

вследствие того что; в связи с тем что и др

что, чтобы; для того чтобы, с тем чтобы и др.

если, ли

как, будто, словно, точно, как будто и др.

несмотря на то что; хотя; как ни…; где ни…;когда ни…

так что

Comment: "Какою" в 3 примере- да, вопросительное местоимение

Answer (score 0):

Вопросительные местоимения всегда стоят в простом предложении и помогают задать вопрос. Если же эти вопросительные или относительные местоимения стоят в сложноподчиненном предложении, то они выполняют роль союзного слова.